# load page before load all async functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `script` *that contains two asynchronous functions*, this page loads immediately, but I have a *value that is updated in one of these asynchronous functions*, so when I try to make a request to my page the page returns the blank value, my idea is to keep the page loading until all asynchronous functions are performed and completed.

Script Functions:

```
  <script>

    let thresh = 0.1

    async function updateResults() {
      if (!isFaceDetectionModelLoaded()) {
        return
      }

      const inputImgEl = $('#inputImg').get(0)
      const options = getFaceDetectorOptions()

      const results = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(inputImgEl, options)
        // compute face landmarks to align faces for better accuracy
        .withFaceLandmarks()
        .withFaceExpressions()


      const canvas = $('#overlay').get(0)
      faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, inputImgEl)

      const resizedResults = faceapi.resizeResults(results, inputImgEl)
      const minConfidence = 0.05
      faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedResults)
      faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedResults, minConfidence)

      var Resultado = JSON.stringify(resizedResults);

      //Procuro as classes
      var stringify = JSON.parse(Resultado);
      var neutro = stringify[0]['expressions']['neutro']
      var feliz = stringify[0]['expressions']['feliz']
      var bravo = stringify[0]['expressions']['bravo']
      var com_medo = stringify[0]['expressions']['com medo']
      var nojo = stringify[0]['expressions']['nojo']
      var surpreso = stringify[0]['expressions']['surpreso']
      var triste = stringify[0]['expressions']['triste']

      var res = stringify[0]['expressions']

      if(feliz == '1') {

        res = "Feliz"

      }


      console.log(feliz)

      console.log(stringify[0]['expressions']);

      $("#Resultado").text(res);




    }

    async function run() {
      // load face detection and face expression recognition models
      // and load face landmark model for face alignment
      await changeFaceDetector(SSD_MOBILENETV1)
      await faceapi.loadFaceLandmarkModel('/')
      await faceapi.loadFaceExpressionModel('/')
      // start processing image


      updateResults()
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

      initImageSelectionControls('webcam.jpg', true)
      initFaceDetectionControls()      
      run()

    })
    var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    $(window).load(function () {
       var endTime = (new Date()).getTime();

       var millisecondsLoading = endTime - startTime;

       console.log(millisecondsLoading);

   });
  </script>
```

NOTE:

The link that access is an API, so the user does not have access to it.

Comment: You can't do that. The page loads synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of `async` functions and `<script async` attribute is to allow page loading to finish without blocking it in any way.

You can store global promise on your initialization:

```
var globalInitializationPromise = run();
```

Then any other code can wait on that:

```
await globalInitializationPromise;
// do stuff
```

Remember that you forgot await in your `run()` implementation:

```
async function run() {
  // load face detection and face expression recognition models
  // and load face landmark model for face alignment
  await changeFaceDetector(SSD_MOBILENETV1)
  await faceapi.loadFaceLandmarkModel('/')
  await faceapi.loadFaceExpressionModel('/')
  // start processing image

  /**AWAIT WAS MISSING HERE! **/ await updateResults()
}
```

Also, if your functions are async, you don't need to run them from `$(document).ready`. Instead, run them immediately as the script loads. If a function needs to access DOM content, it should `await` this promise or something similar:

```
const documentReadyPromise = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        resolve();
    } else {
        function onReady() {
            resolve();
            document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onReady, true);
            window.removeEventListener('load', onReady, true);
        }
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onReady, true);
        window.addEventListener('load', onReady, true);
    }
});
```

Then, in functions that access DOM, do this before accessing it:

```
async function updateResults() {
  if (!isFaceDetectionModelLoaded()) {
    return
  }
  // uses DOM, must wait for HTML:
  await documentReadyPromise;
  // now you can access DOM
  const inputImgEl = $('#inputImg').get(0)
```

Following these rules should positively impact initialization speed of your app, because you can suddenly do a bunch of things while HTML loads.